# What files do what in a release in MVC with visual studio

Tags: asp.net, deployment

If i release(publish) a mvc project to a folder. Lets say I make a change to _layout later in my solution and publish again, what files do i need to update on the ftp? bin or (_layout in views folder)? 
When do I need to update stuff in View or bin?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

bin folder contains your dlls, you project dll let's say `project.dll` is subject to update when you compile your server side code.

Otherwise it is enough update only relevant view file.

You can publish one invidual file thus update it to ftp

[image]